# Can I make new files appear in the right part of the desktop？

Tags: kali-linux

When I download or create a new file, it will appear on the left side of Kali desktop. Is there a way to make the new file appear on the right side, so as MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using XFCE in which case right-click on the Desktop and open `Desktop Settings` or open the Desktop Settings application from the menu.

Then go to the `Icons` tab and select `Icons orientation` to what you want (maybe Top Right Vertical).

Comment: I'm using GNOME, it seems not have this choice.